# Laravel Collection get unique values from nested datastructure

Tags: php, laravel, collections, filter, laravel-5.1

I want to use [Laravel 5.1 Collection's Unique](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-unique) method to filter unique IDs from nested objects.

Given the data structure

```
{
  "key1": [
    {"id": 1},
    {"id": 1}
  ],
  "key2": [
    {"id": 1},
    {"id": 2}
  ]
}
```

I want to return the same datastructure with duplicate `id 1` removed from "key 1".

I wanted to use `$unique = $collection->unique('id');`, but this doesn't seem to apply to a nested datastructure as I have.

So I thought to use $collection

```
    $input = $request->all();

    $collection = collect($input);

    $collection->each(function($obj, $key) {
        //$key is "key1", "key2"
        //obj is the associated array of objects containing IDs
    })->unique('id');
```

I don't quite know how to structure this.

The result structure should be:

```
{
  "key1": [
    {"id": 1}
  ],
  "key2": [
    {"id": 1},
    {"id": 2}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$collection = $collection->map(function ($array) {
    return collect($array)->unique('id')->all();
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If your data structure is nested a single level, be it arrays or objects, simple

```
$unique = $collection->unique('key')
```

does the job.

Answer (score 3):

if you have numeric List then you can use this code

```
$dataList = [1,2,4,5,3,2,1,98,1,2,4,5,6];

$dataList  = collect( $dataList )->unique();
```

you will get all the unique list.

```
[1,2,4,5,3,98,6]
```

Comment: You will get a collection with keys: 
```Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4033 all: [0 => 1,1 => 2,2 => 4,3 => 5,4 => 3,7 => 98,12 => 6, ],}```

Comment: solved by this way

Answer (score 0):

This should also work, assuming I understood your question correctly and you're just trying to use the innermost value as your unique reference

```
$unique = $collection->unique('key.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following.

```
$unique = collect($input)->unique('*.id');
```