# Group algolia results by their duplicates

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

Hi I'm currently using `Laravel-scout` search, Is there a way to get and group the results through their duplicates but with large data?

Example i have a list of country

- New york
- new York
- New Y0rk
- America
- america
- AmericA
- Japan

I want to get the data to become like this

```
New York => [
   'New york' => [],
   'new York' => [],
   'New Y0rk' => [],
],
America => [
   'America' => [],
   'america' => [],
   'AmericA' => [],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use laravel collection and then apply unique on them.
It will help you remove duplicates.

Pls check at [this](https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/22/laravel-5-collections-retrieving-the-distinct-values-of-a-collection-with-unique) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571628/laravel-collection-get-unique-values-from-nested-datastructure) link hope you will get idea.