# How to select distinct records in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to select unique records using `distinct` but I am getting repeated records as I have a value in one field that differs.

Is there a way to specify to exclude this field or can I use `distinct` and specify the column(s) that should be distinct?

My query:

```
Producer::all()->distinct();
```

Comment: Please show us your query to help.

Comment: Producer::all()->distinct();

Comment: Your query should tell which columns you'd like to distinguish by. Also, providing some sample data and the expected result would help us provide you with a good answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Collection get unique values from nested datastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571628/laravel-collection-get-unique-values-from-nested-datastructure)

Comment: @N69S that is on a collection not a query.

Comment: @panthro your `distinct()` is run on a collection resulted from `->all()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Producer::all()`, then you can use `unique`

```
$producers = Producer::all()->unique('name');
```

---

For `distinct`, when you specify a column, it will be distinct

Example

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->select('name', 'email', 'phone')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

Comment: `unique` does not work. Nor does your distinct, it will miss out on selecting certain values on the row.

Comment: Can you share how did you use distinct?

Comment: Producer::all()->distinct();

Comment: Use like this `Producer::all()->distinct('column_name');`

Comment: That does not work.